# two submit buttons on one page always go to first action page

Tags: php, forms, button, submit

I have a php page which has two submit buttons that are meant to do the same thing, but when either are pressed they just go to 'searchLN.php'. When I take away the button and you just press enter on the text it goes to the correct page, what am I doing wrong??

```
<?php
    echo '<h1>Search Patients</h1>';
    echo '<td><form method="post" action="searchLN.php">';
echo 'Search By Patient Last Name :<input type="Text" name="searchPersonLN" class="button">';
    echo '<input type="Submit" name="searchPersonLN" class="button" value="Search" ';
echo '</form></td>';

    echo '<br>';

    echo '<td><form method="post" action="searchID.php">';
echo 'Search By Patient Number :<input type="Text" name="searchPersonID" class="button">';
    echo '<input type="Submit" name="searchPersonID" class="button" value="Search" ';
echo '</form></td>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Return To Main Menu</a>';
?>
```

Comment: You realize in each of your `<form>` both the input and the submit button have the same name attributes?

Comment: Right - as in the name of the input field is the same name as the submit button.  That will cause you problems....

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript which is co-opting the form's submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> echo '<input type="Submit" name="searchPersonLN" class="button" value="Search" ';
> ```

You don't close your input with `>` or `/>`, so, the next line's `</form>` don't close your form.

Comment: Feel like such a n00b! Thanks a million dude